# Hyper-V Windows 8 redirect host network traffic to client VM

Tags: networking, hyper-v, rras, windows-8, network-teaming

I have a Windows 8 pro machine running Hyper-V. This is a laptop with a LAN and a Wifi connection. As a consultant, when I'm on the customer's network, internet access is often limited for the employees, but set open for my machine (largely because I'm assumed to know what I'm doing :).

My issue:

I am often making and killing virtual machines in the course of the time I am there and these machines are restricted in Internet Access. These are usually brand new installs or copies from a clean template. If I'd ask them to get access it wouldn't be an issue (as I said, they trust me), but it's a hassle I'd like to avoid.

My solution:

1. Define two External virtual switches, one for my LAN and one for my
   Wifi.
2. Define an internal virtual switch
3. Set up a Win2008R2 RRAS VM.
4. Connect the three virtual switches to the RRAS.
5. Set up the RRAS to team the LAN and Wifi, set up NAT and provide the Internal network with Internet/network no matter which adapter is connected.
6. Connect all other virtual machines AND the Windows 8 host-OS to the Internal network.

My question:

A) Is the RRAS thing (step 5) feasible?

B) Can I deny my host OS direct access to my LAN and Wifi connection? I'm fine with seeing the adapters, but I want all traffic redirected over the Internal network.

If need be I can:

- Make the RRAS server Win 2012
- Make my Host OS Win 2012

(which would both involve badgering our IT-guy for the product key :p)

**EDIT:**

Win2012 supports teaming network adapters, so if I change my host OS to Win2012 I MIGHT be able to team the LAN and Wifi there and "share" it's connection with the internal network. That'd require reinstalling my system, so It's a last ditch solution.

Comment: Not really a solution, hence the comment, but I simply use VMware Workstation with NAT'd network connections. Does Win 8 Hyper-V not have a similar option?

Comment: It does: If you have a single network connection you can "share" it with an virtual Internal network. But you can't "team" two network connections in Win8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After fiddling around with this idea on various laptops:

- Windows Server 2012 does not allow a Wifi connection to be part of a NIC team
- You CAN deny the host OS (or "management OS") access to your Phycical NICs:

  1. Create an external Virtual Switch (if not already made).
  2. Uncheck "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter".

[Source](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/management/managing-hyper-v-networking.html)

- This enables my "use a 2012 RRAS server to team and share the network connections" idea.

Comment: I was holding out a bit longer to see if it triggered a better idea with anyone else. But yeah, that time has passed.